# As a result of analysis using wordscores in quenteda, why does the wordscores value of the reference text change from the initially specified value?

Tags: r

Is the target of rescaling in quenteda virgin text or reference text?

I understand that the results analyzed with wordscores in quenteda are rescaled results. How can I check the raw scores?

I read the paper by laver and benoit, and according to the paper, the target for rescaling appears to be virgin text, but I don't know why the score of the reference text changes in quenteda.